# Why does painted_img always remain zero in my Python code?

Tags: python, numpy, logical-operators

I'm encountering an issue with the following code snippet in Python. Despite my efforts, the variable painted_img always remains filled with zeros (0), it is for sure that sp_intensity[seg] is not filled with zeros (0).

```
self.painted_imgs = []
self.labels = labels
for idx, (sp_intensity, _, sp_order, superpixels) in enumerate(sp_data):
    painted_img = np.zeros_like(images[idx])
    for seg in sp_order:
        mask = (superpixels == seg)
        painted_img[mask] = sp_intensity[seg]
    self.painted_imgs.append(painted_img)
```

And the detail of shape information is below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBYzy.png)

Comment: The line `mask = (superpixels == seg)` makes `mask` a Boolean. Is that deliberate? You use it as a key on a dict just after that.

Comment: What's the `dtype` of `painted_img`?  Did you check `mask` for one or more `seg`?  In short test one or more `seg` in more detail.

Comment: @Chris, Yes using mask as a boolean is intentional in this case. The expression (superpixels == seg) creates a boolean mask which is then used to select elements from painted_img for assignment.

Comment: @Chris, @hpaulj, thanks for all your suggestions. It seems that the issue lies with the `dtype` of `painted_img`, which is inferred as `np.uint8`. This data type causes the values in `painted_img` to remain at 0 when assigned from `sp_intensity[seg]` of `np.float32`.